# Run Optaplanner Project Job Scheduling Example But Get Different Result

Tags: java, optaplanner

I tried to reproduce the example of Project Job Scheduling in Optaplanner manual, like in this picture below: 
[image]

Here is the xml sample data:

```
<PjsSchedule id="0">
    <id>0</id>
    <projectList id="1">
        <PjsProject id="book1">
            <id>0</id>
            <releaseDate>0</releaseDate>
            <criticalPathDuration>7</criticalPathDuration>
            <localResourceList id="2" />
            <jobList id="3">
                <PjsJob id="119">
                    <id>0</id>
                    <project reference="book1"/>
                    <jobType>SOURCE</jobType>
                    <executionModeList id="11910">
                        <PjsExecutionMode id="11911">
                            <id>0</id>
                            <job reference="119"/>
                            <duration>0</duration>
                            <resourceRequirementList id="1192"/>
                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                    </executionModeList>
                    <successorJobList id="11913">
                        <PjsJob id="design1">
                            <id>1</id>
                            <project reference="book1"/>
                            <jobType>STANDARD</jobType>
                            <executionModeList id="4">
                                <PjsExecutionMode id="5">
                                    <id>0</id>
                                    <job reference="design1"/>
                                    <duration>2</duration>
                                    <resourceRequirementList id="6">
                                        <PjsResourceRequirement id="7">
                                            <id>0</id>
                                            <executionMode reference="5"/>
                                            <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" id="designer">
                                                <id>0</id>
                                                <capacity>1</capacity>
                                            </resource>
                                            <requirement>1</requirement>
                                        </PjsResourceRequirement>
                                    </resourceRequirementList>
                                </PjsExecutionMode>
                            </executionModeList>
                            <successorJobList id="8">
                                <PjsJob id="cover1">
                                    <id>2</id>
                                    <project reference="book1"/>
                                    <jobType>STANDARD</jobType>
                                    <executionModeList id="9">
                                        <PjsExecutionMode id="10">
                                            <id>1</id>
                                            <job reference="cover1"/>
                                            <duration>3</duration>
                                            <resourceRequirementList id="11">
                                                <PjsResourceRequirement id="12">
                                                    <id>1</id>
                                                    <executionMode reference="10"/>
                                                    <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" id="worker1">
                                                        <id>1</id>
                                                        <capacity>1</capacity>
                                                    </resource>
                                                    <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                </PjsResourceRequirement>
                                            </resourceRequirementList>
                                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                                        <PjsExecutionMode id="101">
                                            <id>1011</id>
                                            <job reference="cover1"/>
                                            <duration>3</duration>
                                            <resourceRequirementList id="10111">
                                                <PjsResourceRequirement id="10112">
                                                    <id>1011</id>
                                                    <executionMode reference="101"/>
                                                    <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" id="worker2">
                                                        <id>2</id>
                                                        <capacity>1</capacity>
                                                    </resource>
                                                    <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                </PjsResourceRequirement>
                                            </resourceRequirementList>
                                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                                    </executionModeList>
                                    <successorJobList id="14">
                                        <PjsJob id="assembly1">
                                            <id>4</id>
                                            <project reference="book1"/>
                                            <jobType>STANDARD</jobType>
                                            <executionModeList id="15">
                                                <PjsExecutionMode id="16">
                                                    <id>2</id>
                                                    <job reference="assembly1"/>
                                                    <duration>1</duration>
                                                    <resourceRequirementList id="17">
                                                        <PjsResourceRequirement id="18">
                                                            <id>3</id>
                                                            <executionMode reference="16"/>
                                                            <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" reference="worker1"/>
                                                            <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                        </PjsResourceRequirement>
                                                    </resourceRequirementList>
                                                </PjsExecutionMode>
                                                <PjsExecutionMode id="161">
                                                    <id>1612</id>
                                                    <job reference="assembly1"/>
                                                    <duration>1</duration>
                                                    <resourceRequirementList id="16117">
                                                        <PjsResourceRequirement id="16118">
                                                            <id>1613</id>
                                                            <executionMode reference="161"/>
                                                            <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" reference="worker2"/>
                                                            <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                        </PjsResourceRequirement>
                                                    </resourceRequirementList>
                                                </PjsExecutionMode>
                                            </executionModeList>
                                            <successorJobList id="20">
                                                <PjsJob id="175">
                                                    <id>5</id>
                                                    <project reference="book1"/>
                                                    <jobType>SINK</jobType>
                                                    <executionModeList id="17576">
                                                        <PjsExecutionMode id="17577">
                                                            <id>17531</id>
                                                            <job reference="175"/>
                                                            <duration>0</duration>
                                                            <resourceRequirementList id="17578"/>
                                                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                                                    </executionModeList>
                                                    <successorJobList id="17579"/>
                                                </PjsJob>
                                            </successorJobList>
                                        </PjsJob>
                                    </successorJobList>
                                </PjsJob>
                                <PjsJob id="pages400">
                                    <id>3</id>
                                    <project reference="book1"/>
                                    <jobType>STANDARD</jobType>
                                    <executionModeList id="21">
                                        <PjsExecutionMode id="22">
                                            <id>3</id>
                                            <job reference="pages400"/>
                                            <duration>4</duration>
                                            <resourceRequirementList id="23">
                                                <PjsResourceRequirement id="24">
                                                    <id>5</id>
                                                    <executionMode reference="22"/>
                                                    <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" reference="worker1"/>
                                                    <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                </PjsResourceRequirement>
                                            </resourceRequirementList>
                                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                                        <PjsExecutionMode id="221">
                                            <id>2213</id>
                                            <job reference="pages400"/>
                                            <duration>4</duration>
                                            <resourceRequirementList id="22123">
                                                <PjsResourceRequirement id="22124">
                                                    <id>2215</id>
                                                    <executionMode reference="221"/>
                                                    <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" reference="worker2"/>
                                                    <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                </PjsResourceRequirement>
                                            </resourceRequirementList>
                                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                                    </executionModeList>
                                    <successorJobList id="26">
                                        <PjsJob reference="assembly1"/>
                                    </successorJobList>
                                </PjsJob>
                            </successorJobList>
                        </PjsJob>
                    </successorJobList>
                </PjsJob>
                <PjsJob reference="design1"/>
                <PjsJob reference="cover1"/>
                <PjsJob reference="pages400"/>
                <PjsJob reference="assembly1"/>
                <PjsJob reference="175"/>
            </jobList>
        </PjsProject>
        <PjsProject id="book2">
            <id>1</id>
            <releaseDate>0</releaseDate>
            <criticalPathDuration>8</criticalPathDuration>
            <localResourceList id="27" />
            <jobList id="28">
                <PjsJob id="219">
                    <id>6</id>
                    <project reference="book2"/>
                    <jobType>SOURCE</jobType>
                    <executionModeList id="21910">
                        <PjsExecutionMode id="21911">
                            <id>0</id>
                            <job reference="219"/>
                            <duration>0</duration>
                            <resourceRequirementList id="2192"/>
                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                    </executionModeList>
                    <successorJobList id="21913">
                        <PjsJob id="design2">
                            <id>7</id>
                            <project reference="book2"/>
                            <jobType>STANDARD</jobType>
                            <executionModeList id="29">
                                <PjsExecutionMode id="30">
                                    <id>5</id>
                                    <job reference="design2"/>
                                    <duration>2</duration>
                                    <resourceRequirementList id="31">
                                        <PjsResourceRequirement id="32">
                                            <id>7</id>
                                            <executionMode reference="30"/>
                                            <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" reference="designer"/>
                                            <requirement>1</requirement>
                                        </PjsResourceRequirement>
                                    </resourceRequirementList>
                                </PjsExecutionMode>
                            </executionModeList>
                            <successorJobList id="31">
                                <PjsJob id="cover2">
                                    <id>8</id>
                                    <project reference="book2"/>
                                    <jobType>STANDARD</jobType>
                                    <executionModeList id="32">
                                        <PjsExecutionMode id="33">
                                            <id>5</id>
                                            <job reference="cover2"/>
                                            <duration>3</duration>
                                            <resourceRequirementList id="34">
                                                <PjsResourceRequirement id="35">
                                                    <id>8</id>
                                                    <executionMode reference="33"/>
                                                    <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" reference="worker1"/>
                                                    <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                </PjsResourceRequirement>
                                            </resourceRequirementList>
                                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                                        <PjsExecutionMode id="331">
                                            <id>3315</id>
                                            <job reference="cover2"/>
                                            <duration>3</duration>
                                            <resourceRequirementList id="33134">
                                                <PjsResourceRequirement id="33135">
                                                    <id>3318</id>
                                                    <executionMode reference="331"/>
                                                    <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" reference="worker2"/>
                                                    <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                </PjsResourceRequirement>
                                            </resourceRequirementList>
                                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                                    </executionModeList>
                                    <successorJobList id="34">
                                        <PjsJob id="assembly2">
                                            <id>10</id>
                                            <project reference="book2"/>
                                            <jobType>STANDARD</jobType>
                                            <executionModeList id="35">
                                                <PjsExecutionMode id="36">
                                                    <id>366</id>
                                                    <job reference="assembly2"/>
                                                    <duration>1</duration>
                                                    <resourceRequirementList id="37">
                                                        <PjsResourceRequirement id="38">
                                                            <id>383</id>
                                                            <executionMode reference="36"/>
                                                            <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" reference="worker1"/>
                                                            <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                        </PjsResourceRequirement>                                               
                                                    </resourceRequirementList>
                                                </PjsExecutionMode>
                                                <PjsExecutionMode id="361">
                                                    <id>3661</id>
                                                    <job reference="assembly2"/>
                                                    <duration>1</duration>
                                                    <resourceRequirementList id="371">
                                                        <PjsResourceRequirement id="381">
                                                            <id>3831</id>
                                                            <executionMode reference="361"/>
                                                            <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" reference="worker2"/>
                                                            <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                        </PjsResourceRequirement>                                               
                                                    </resourceRequirementList>
                                                </PjsExecutionMode>
                                            </executionModeList>
                                            <successorJobList id="39">
                                                <PjsJob id="275">
                                                    <id>11</id>
                                                    <project reference="book2"/>
                                                    <jobType>SINK</jobType>
                                                    <executionModeList id="27576">
                                                        <PjsExecutionMode id="27577">
                                                            <id>27531</id>
                                                            <job reference="275"/>
                                                            <duration>0</duration>
                                                            <resourceRequirementList id="27578"/>
                                                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                                                    </executionModeList>
                                                    <successorJobList id="27579"/>
                                                </PjsJob>
                                            </successorJobList>
                                        </PjsJob>
                                    </successorJobList>
                                </PjsJob>
                                <PjsJob id="pages500">
                                    <id>9</id>
                                    <project reference="book2"/>
                                    <jobType>STANDARD</jobType>
                                    <executionModeList id="40">
                                        <PjsExecutionMode id="41">
                                            <id>413</id>
                                            <job reference="pages500"/>
                                            <duration>5</duration>
                                            <resourceRequirementList id="42">
                                                <PjsResourceRequirement id="43">
                                                    <id>435</id>
                                                    <executionMode reference="41"/>
                                                    <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" reference="worker1"/>
                                                    <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                </PjsResourceRequirement>                                       
                                            </resourceRequirementList>
                                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                                        <PjsExecutionMode id="411">
                                            <id>4131</id>
                                            <job reference="pages500"/>
                                            <duration>5</duration>
                                            <resourceRequirementList id="421">
                                                <PjsResourceRequirement id="431">
                                                    <id>4351</id>
                                                    <executionMode reference="411"/>
                                                    <resource class="PjsGlobalResource" reference="worker2"/>
                                                    <requirement>1</requirement>
                                                </PjsResourceRequirement>                                       
                                            </resourceRequirementList>
                                        </PjsExecutionMode>
                                    </executionModeList>
                                    <successorJobList id="44">
                                        <PjsJob reference="assembly2"/>
                                    </successorJobList>
                                </PjsJob>
                            </successorJobList>
                        </PjsJob>
                    </successorJobList>
                </PjsJob>               
                <PjsJob reference="design2"/>
                <PjsJob reference="cover2"/>
                <PjsJob reference="pages500"/>
                <PjsJob reference="assembly2"/>
                <PjsJob reference="275"/>
            </jobList>
        </PjsProject>
    </projectList>
    <jobList id="366">
        <PjsJob reference="119"/>
        <PjsJob reference="design1"/>
        <PjsJob reference="cover1"/>
        <PjsJob reference="pages400"/>
        <PjsJob reference="assembly1"/>
        <PjsJob reference="175"/>
        <PjsJob reference="219"/>
        <PjsJob reference="design2"/>
        <PjsJob reference="cover2"/>
        <PjsJob reference="pages500"/>
        <PjsJob reference="assembly2"/>
        <PjsJob reference="275"/>
    </jobList>
    <executionModeList id="367">
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="11910"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="21910"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="17577"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="27577"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="5"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="10"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="101"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="16"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="161"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="22"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="221"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="30"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="33"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="331"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="36"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="361"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="41"/>
        <PjsExecutionMode reference="411"/>
    </executionModeList>
    <resourceList id="368">
        <PjsGlobalResource reference="designer"/>
        <PjsGlobalResource reference="worker1"/>
        <PjsGlobalResource reference="worker2"/>
    </resourceList>
    <resourceRequirementList id="369">
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="7"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="12"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="10112"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="18"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="16118"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="24"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="22124"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="32"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="35"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="33135"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="38"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="381"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="43"/>
        <PjsResourceRequirement reference="431"/>
    </resourceRequirementList>
    <allocationList id="370">
        <PjsAllocation id="a1">
            <id>0</id>
            <job reference="119"/>
            <sourceAllocation reference="a1"/>
            <sinkAllocation id="a2">
                <id>5</id>
                <job reference="175"/>
                <sourceAllocation reference="a1"/>
                <sinkAllocation reference="a2"/>
                <predecessorAllocationList id="373">
                    <PjsAllocation id="a3">
                        <id>4</id>
                        <job reference="assembly1"/>
                        <sourceAllocation reference="a1"/>
                        <sinkAllocation reference="a2"/>
                        <predecessorAllocationList id="4051">
                            <PjsAllocation id="a4">
                                <id>2</id>
                                <job reference="cover1"/>
                                <sourceAllocation reference="a1"/>
                                <sinkAllocation reference="a2"/>
                                <predecessorAllocationList id="4251">
                                    <PjsAllocation id="a5">
                                        <id>1</id>
                                        <job reference="design1"/>
                                        <sourceAllocation reference="a1"/>
                                        <sinkAllocation reference="a2"/>
                                        <predecessorAllocationList id="4252">
                                            <PjsAllocation reference="a1"/>
                                        </predecessorAllocationList>
                                        <successorAllocationList id="4261">
                                            <PjsAllocation reference="a4"/>
                                            <PjsAllocation id="a6">
                                                <id>3</id>
                                                <job reference="pages400"/>
                                                <sourceAllocation reference="a1"/>
                                                <sinkAllocation reference="a2"/>
                                                <predecessorAllocationList id="4253">
                                                    <PjsAllocation reference="a5"/>
                                                </predecessorAllocationList>
                                                <successorAllocationList id="4263">
                                                    <PjsAllocation reference="a3"/>
                                                </successorAllocationList>
                                                <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
                                            </PjsAllocation>
                                        </successorAllocationList>
                                        <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
                                    </PjsAllocation>        
                                </predecessorAllocationList>
                                <successorAllocationList id="4262">
                                    <PjsAllocation reference="a3"/>
                                </successorAllocationList>
                                <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
                            </PjsAllocation>
                            <PjsAllocation reference="a6"/>
                        </predecessorAllocationList>
                        <successorAllocationList id="4061">
                            <PjsAllocation reference="a2"/>
                        </successorAllocationList>
                        <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
                    </PjsAllocation>
                </predecessorAllocationList>
                <successorAllocationList id="4161"/>
                <executionMode reference="17577"/>
                <delay>0</delay>
                <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
            </sinkAllocation>
            <predecessorAllocationList id="405"/>
            <successorAllocationList id="406">
                <PjsAllocation reference="a5"/>
            </successorAllocationList>
            <executionMode reference="11911"/>
            <delay>0</delay>
            <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
        </PjsAllocation>
        <PjsAllocation reference="a5"/>
        <PjsAllocation reference="a4"/>
        <PjsAllocation reference="a6"/>
        <PjsAllocation reference="a3"/>
        <PjsAllocation reference="a2"/>
        <PjsAllocation id="b1">
            <id>6</id>
            <job reference="219"/>
            <sourceAllocation reference="b1"/>
            <sinkAllocation id="b2">
                <id>11</id>
                <job reference="275"/>
                <sourceAllocation reference="b1"/>
                <sinkAllocation reference="b2"/>
                <predecessorAllocationList id="273">
                    <PjsAllocation id="b3">
                        <id>10</id>
                        <job reference="assembly2"/>
                        <sourceAllocation reference="b1"/>
                        <sinkAllocation reference="b2"/>
                        <predecessorAllocationList id="2051">
                            <PjsAllocation id="b4">
                                <id>8</id>
                                <job reference="cover2"/>
                                <sourceAllocation reference="b1"/>
                                <sinkAllocation reference="b2"/>
                                <predecessorAllocationList id="2251">
                                    <PjsAllocation id="b5">
                                        <id>7</id>
                                        <job reference="design2"/>
                                        <sourceAllocation reference="b1"/>
                                        <sinkAllocation reference="b2"/>
                                        <predecessorAllocationList id="2252">
                                            <PjsAllocation reference="b1"/>
                                        </predecessorAllocationList>
                                        <successorAllocationList id="2261">
                                            <PjsAllocation reference="b4"/>
                                            <PjsAllocation id="b6">
                                                <id>9</id>
                                                <job reference="pages500"/>
                                                <sourceAllocation reference="b1"/>
                                                <sinkAllocation reference="b2"/>
                                                <predecessorAllocationList id="2253">
                                                    <PjsAllocation reference="b5"/>
                                                </predecessorAllocationList>
                                                <successorAllocationList id="2263">
                                                    <PjsAllocation reference="b3"/>
                                                </successorAllocationList>
                                                <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
                                            </PjsAllocation>
                                        </successorAllocationList>
                                        <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
                                    </PjsAllocation>        
                                </predecessorAllocationList>
                                <successorAllocationList id="2262">
                                    <PjsAllocation reference="b3"/>
                                </successorAllocationList>
                                <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
                            </PjsAllocation>
                            <PjsAllocation reference="b6"/>
                        </predecessorAllocationList>
                        <successorAllocationList id="2061">
                            <PjsAllocation reference="b2"/>
                        </successorAllocationList>
                        <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
                    </PjsAllocation>
                </predecessorAllocationList>
                <successorAllocationList id="2161"/>
                <executionMode reference="27577"/>
                <delay>0</delay>
                <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
            </sinkAllocation>
            <predecessorAllocationList id="205"/>
            <successorAllocationList id="206">
                <PjsAllocation reference="b5"/>
            </successorAllocationList>
            <executionMode reference="21911"/>
            <delay>0</delay>
            <predecessorsDoneDate>0</predecessorsDoneDate>
        </PjsAllocation>
        <PjsAllocation reference="b5"/>
        <PjsAllocation reference="b4"/>
        <PjsAllocation reference="b6"/>
        <PjsAllocation reference="b3"/>
        <PjsAllocation reference="b2"/>
    </allocationList>
</PjsSchedule>
```

The result when I tried to solve it using Optaplanner examples application was not like the result in the picture, instead it look like this:
[image]

From the result, it show that design job from project 0 (job 1) and project 1 (job 7) executed parallel, while the designer resource only 1 person. Please help me, what mistake have I done? and how to solve it?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Interesting, that should work indeed. Why isn't the hard constraint being trigged and affecting the score in the bottom of the window? Have you made any other edits than the input xml file? Try downloading an OptaPlanner distribution zip from scratch and using that one to open that input file.

Comment: I haven't made any other edits rather than creating a new input xml file. Okay, I will to to run it using OptaPlanner distribution zip from scratch, and will update the progress to here soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this answer in case someone who may run into the same or similar problem with me. First of all, I run the xml input file (posted in my question) using Optaplanner examples that I run from eclipse (the source code was imported and completely unedited from distribution zip), and it give me the first result in my question post.
Then I tried to run Optaplanner from distribution zip (using the runExamples.bat) and try to solve the xml input file, and it give me the expected result:
[image]

When I dig deeper, it turn out the projectJobSchedulingScoreRules.drl may have a bug. I tried to change the score calculator from scoreDrl to incrementalScoreCalculatorClass, and now it give me the expected result. I hope the Optaplanner team aware of this issue.